# No such file or directory when generate framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

When I make a new framework with aggregate to generate universal framework , but a error present , as follow :

```
cp: build/Release-iphoneos/TEST.framework/: No such file or directory 
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: build/Release-iphoneos/TEST.framework/TEST (No such file or directory) 
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

And here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

This is a new target , I only want to test generate framework , but fail!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said, no `TEST.framework` can be found in the path `<PROJECT_DIR>/build/Release-iphoneos/TEST.framework`.

You need to check the script you use, or the blog post which you reference is out-date.

Answer (score 0):

First you should build the target specified in `xcodebuild` command directly to see if it can build succeed.

Check what the actual build path is. If the path(`build/`) is not exist, you can try to specified the build path for `xcodebuild`, `OBJROOT=${WRK_DIR} SYMROOT=${WRK_DIR}`